# lightbox2 - cant see images in "big" when clicked on in Internet Explore

Tags: lightbox2

i have images from SQL, and i cant get them to show in lightbox2 when they are clicked on, in IE, i can in Chrome and FF. i can load all the images when i try Chrome, and FF, and mobile and tablets can show it, no problem there, only in IE there is a problem, 
Do any one have an idea what can be the problem?

```
<!-- Lightbox -->
<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center PackShots">
                <a href="<%# Eval("ImageURL") %>" data-lightbox="<%# Eval("CollectionsName") %>" title="Collection: <%# Eval("CollectionsName") %> | Style No. <%# Eval("StyleNo") %>">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageURL") %>' runat="server" alt='<%# Eval("Name") %>' /></a>
                <p class="poppins">Collection: <%# Eval("CollectionsName") %></p>
                <p class="poppins">Style No. <%# Eval("StyleNo") %> </p>



            </div >
```